# Why are some 32-bit PC games not supported on 64-bit operating systems?

Tags: pc, backwards-compatibility

I have the original box-copy of "Medal of Honor Airborne", where the system requirements state that the game cannot be played on Windows Vista 64-bit. Why are some games not supported on 64-bit operating systems?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/old-windows-games-not-working-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: Not sure it's technically a duplicate but it does answer the question more directly and with more quality

Answer (score 9, accepted):

32 bit games can run 64 bit Windows, typically without any issues.  Older 16 bit games designed for Windows XP or earlier will not run on Windows Vista/7 64 bit.

Many times, software and games will claim they do not run on a particular operating system (Windows Vista 64 bit in this case) simply because they don't want to allocate resources to test on that particular system or support it.  According to [this forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/gaming/90311-medal-honor-airborne-problems.html#post447263), Medal of Honor: Airborne runs just fine on Vista 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's interesting that I couldn't even install the game. It just rejects to install on Vista x64.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the installer program is 16 bit but the actual game is 32 bit.  I would try installing the game on a virtual machine and then simply copying the game directory to your Vista machine and run it.  Usually old games don't touch the registry.

Comment: I seriously doubt that. It's the UT3 engine, so it's definitely 64-bit compatible. The installer is just set-up to refuse to install on a 64-bit system because EA doesn't want to have to deal with 64-bit problems. IE laziness. Just run the installer in compatibility mode as marco suggested.

Comment: Why wouldn't a 16 bit game run on 32 bit Windows Vista or Windows 7?

Comment: I believe 32-bit versions of Vista and 7 can run 16-bit programs in compatibility mode (natively, without a virtual machine) as they have WoW (Windows on Windows, not WOW64).

Answer (score 4):

For **some** games (not all unfortunately) that worked well in previous Windows versions (e.g. Windows XP), in Vista or Windows 7 you have the possibility to start the game in **compatibility mode**.

Just right-click on the executable, select **Properties** and in the **Compatibilty** tab choose Windows XP and try. Same for installers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to run the software in Windows 7's [XP-mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx), which simulates a complete and independent Windows XP within your machine.

Comment: Win7 *Professional* and above only. It's VMs for the rest of them.