# Osmos lag on older pc

Tags: windows-7, osmos

I installed Osmos the other day on an older PC.

I started the game and it lags so much that I dont even get to see the menu screen.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

The PC specs are as follows:

- CPU: AMD Dual Core 3800+
- GFX Card: ATI X1600
- OS: Win7 Professional
- RAM: 3Gb

Comment: is your win 32bit or 64bit? In the latter case, there is [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/old-windows-games-not-working-on-64-bit-windows) which might be interesting because of the answer [on win7's xp mode](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/old-windows-games-not-working-on-64-bit-windows/1395#1395).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant exactly remember how I came about the link, but [over here](http://downloads.guru3d.com/DNA-ATI-Windows-Vista-32-bit-download-2081.html) is a driver that I downloaded and installed.

I tried running Osmos again and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm afraid it's pretty easy. The video card you're using is quite old, and it doesn't support Windows 7. Seeing as Osmos is a relatively new game, it's going to be slow.

You could try updating drivers, but seeing as ATI doesn't support Windows 7 for that card, it might or might not be successful.

Comment: sigh. not exactly the answer i was looking for. but thank you none the less.

Comment: I figured that. PC technology moves too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and my machine is fairly new.

In the [FAQ](http://www.hemispheregames.com/faq/#tech_hotrod), they explain that this can happen if your video drivers don't support transparency/alpha-blending well.

I had assumed that since Windows 7 included video drivers in the automatic updates, I was all set, but I needed to install new drivers to even get to the menu. After updating, it runs smooth as silk.

Comment: I downloaded a new driver that I hope is going to work for this. But I am not holding my breath

Answer (score 1):

It runs *almost* smoothly on my 750 MHz Notebook with an ATI Rage on WinXP, so I guess Win7 is the problem.

However, you could use a small Linux Distro with a *current* [wine](http://winehq.org), Osmos runs great on my Athlon XP 1800+ with ATI Mobility Radeon 9200 under Ubuntu 8.04. Just remember to reinstall OpenAL for Osmos to run. If you don't want to bother with partitioning I recommend using [wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/), which installs [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com) as an image file on your NTFS partition.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try if the new driver doesnt work.