# How can I make Skip98 work on a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, backwards-compatibility, skip98

My Mother in law was playing to an old freeware [Skip-bo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip-bo) game on her Windows XP computer, it's called Skip98. You could still find it by goggling it, but the original site is down.

She bought a new Laptop, it came with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and I cannot get this old game working on it, I get corrupted graphics.

I check this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/old-windows-games-not-working-on-64-bit-windows), but she has Home Premium version, so Microsoft state that :

> You are not eligible to download
>   Windows XP Mode. You must have Windows
>   7 Professional, Enterprise, or
>   Ultimate to run Windows XP Mode. To
>   upgrade visit Windows 7 Anytime
>   Upgrade.

And she is not interested in upgrading to "get a free game working".

Meanwhile, I found a [browser version](http://richapps.webs.com/SkipWE.html), by the same programmer, but she likes to play when she doesn't have Internet access (example, at theirs holiday home).

How could I get it to work, or is there any free alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of SkipWE. I created a ZIP file which should allow you to run SkipWE without internet access.  Simply download the file from the link below, extract it to your desktop (or elsewhere), then double-click the "SkipWE.exe" file. Hopefully that will work at your mother's holiday home :)

FILE: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=78RHS2UQ

Enjoy!

-PF

Comment: I always love it when the author of a program steps in and makes something work just so a single person can enjoy it.

Comment: Well, I sent him an email pointing to this question after your last comment. He was kind enough to step in and save the day!

Comment: Hi again. There are new versions of this app. There's SkipTouch for iPhone, iPad and Android. And there's SkipWE on Facebook. Links available from http://rich-apps.com/

Comment: @RichApps I know this is an old post, but the download link is broken and rich-apps.com doesn't have this downloadable PC version. Is there a chance you could add it to your site? :)

Comment: The download link is currently unavailable due to the shutdown of Megaupload. Anyone know of a different link?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the game works it may be possible to "download" the online version of the game. From a cursory glance over it it looks like all you'd have to do is download all resources for it(as in, there is no server side dependency).

Also, the site is hosted on Free Webs which I know does not allow any server-side code. So, what I would do is get a copy of Firefox along with the Firebug extension. Browse to http://richapps.webs.com/SkipWE.html and open up Firebug's "NET" tab. This will show you every request the web page makes. Using this list of requests, just download all of the resources that it loads and save them all in a folder with a proper relative path.

When you get all the files downloaded to a local folder you can just open up the webpage off of your local computer and it should just work. It may take some trial and error to get to that point though.

Comment: The idea is good, I will give it a try.

Comment: Don't work, Right now. the game does not seem to "reset" itself correctly (look like it keep the state when i saved it). I got some problem downloading the ".i" files that redirect to a dotI.jsp. Do you know a tool that will download all those files? Anyway, I think that the ".jsp" file is a server-side code file, isn't it?

Comment: @Dav yes sorry, `.jsp` is for Java server-side code. This approach won't work then unless you were to somehow reverse engineer what the server is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If she has a version of Windows XP, she can install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Windows XP inside of it, as an alternative way to use XP Mode.

Of course, you will need to have a Windows XP licence for this to work since this is only allowed with a 7-only licence for Windows 7 Professional and higher, as you noted already.

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion but I don't have any Windows XP licence for her. And the overhead (having to start the Virtual PC, wait that it boot and finally run the game) will discourage her. And I don't mention all the windows updates that will pop-up every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Well Usually I can set compatability on old games ot get them to work. Right click / Properties. Set compatability to Windows XP and make sure desktop composition is off. If this doesn't work and you don't have an answer tonight, I will try when I get home. 7 not at work yet.

Comment: Strangely, I got a message stating that I need the x64 version for that program when I try to run it on my computer.

Comment: Precision, I got this message when testing on my win7 box, not my in law's laptop. Gonna try next time I see her.