# How do I play the original Dungeon Siege on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, dungeon-siege

I have installed and attempted to play the original Dungeon Siege on my Windows 7 64 bit computer.

The game runs, but it is horrible choppy and basically unplayable.  Looking around it looks like it is a known issue.

Has anyone out there been able to get this game working in Win7 64bit? Or is my solution going to be a virtual machine to XP or something?

(I would like to know if there are other options before I go through all the steps to set up a virtual machine.)

Comment: Have you tried running the program in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the DSVideoConfig.exe in the installation directory, and explicitly select your video card (rather than the default "Primary Display Driver - Hardware" or "TnL").

Also, it looks like an additional step is needed for Legend of Aranna to work.  Copy the first line from the DungeonSiege.ini file in the Dungeon Siege folder to the DungeonSiege.ini file in the LoA folder.

([Source](http://deathmarine.com/dungeon-siege-and-windows-7-x64/))

Answer (score -2):

Running compatibility in Vista might help as well. I saw it on another forum and it worked for me with a downloaded fix from [MegaGames](http://www.megagames.com)

Answer (score -3):

Depending which version of Windows 7 you're running XP Mode might be an easy answer, yes it  does put it in a virtual machines, but the VM is pretty much invisible and doesn't get in the way or seem like it's in a VM.

See this previous question [Old Windows games not working on 64-bit Windows](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/old-windows-games-not-working-on-64-bit-windows).

Comment: Also it does not support hardware acceleration, which means the game would not run at all. Even if it would it would be even slower.