# How can I play Indiana Jones: The Infernal Machine on Windows 8?

Tags: indiana-jones-infernal-machine

Due to it being designed for prehistoric computers I can't run it on my Windows 8 laptop. How can I go about making it run on a current operating system?

EDIT: To avoid any confusion, the game can boot normally, but after 4 or so minutes after opening it, it starts gliching, and bugging to the point where it hangs and then crashes.

Comment: Seems unlikely. If it were a dos game, you could try dosbox, but it seems to be one of the few games designed for 16-bit Windows specifically.

Comment: I heard, aren't there any compatibility programms? I mean, this is one of the best games ever made, and not being able to play it is sad. I somehow got Grim fadango to run to my computer, so, I am hoping it is possible to get this masterpiece as well. ALSO: Yea, but what would tagspam be? A question has tags, if you seach something within the tag, you find a question. Anyway, I suppose I understand.

Comment: you could use some virtualisation software to set up a Win 98 vm, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-to-get-old-16-bit-windows-games-to-work-on-64-bit-windows) contains the answer you seek?

Comment: ... although instead of [Windows XP Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_Mode#Windows_XP_Mode), Windows 8 has [Hyper-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V)

Comment: Nono, the game runs, till a certain level, it boots, but starts gliching and bugging and crashing after about 4 minutes of being open. I will try to use this regardles.

Comment: Have you tried XP compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can just run an older version of windows on Virtual Box or VMWare Workstation. You can play it on the Virtual Machine

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of posterity, [there is an unofficial installer](http://markusegger.at/Games) for Windows 7+ and [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4521785/indypx64.exe) which I found on a forum. I just confirmed that running it from the installed folder makes the Jones3d.exe compatible with Windows 10.

Also, if that doesn't help and you don't have a legit license for an older version of Windows [there are reports](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5190) you can use Linux with Wine to play. And Linux can run in a virtual machine itself if you'd rather not use it as your general-purpose OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried buying it from GoG? (https://www.gog.com/game/indiana_jones_and_the_infernal_machine)

Their game page details that it works on Win7, 8 and 10.

[image]

GoG optimize old games to run on newer systems, and games bought through them are covered by their [Money Back guarantee](https://support.gog.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000487189-Money-Back-Guarantee-Policy#en-US) which covers instances where they don't work. This is probably your best bet.